# Ability to change what 'this' refers to in Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to recreate some sort of Piano Tiles in Windows Forms but I am having some issues. The game relies on a layout of 4x4 panels that will change colors at random. I have a starting function that will assign a random panel on each row to be changed to black. I have another function that will work its way up the panels to move each black panel down one. Right now I have this assigned to a button so I know it works but I am trying to figure out how to move the panels down only when the player has clicked on the one black panel on the bottom row. If the player does not click the black panel and instead clicks a white panel it will be game over and the wrong panel will change to red. [see photo][Basic Game][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc32y.png)

The issue I seem to be coming across is that I want to have the 4 panels at the bottom all have the same click event that will check the color of the panel and perform the necessary actions. I thought my code would work but it does not.

```
 private void regclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.BackColor== Color.White)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
            MessageBox.Show("Game Over");
            clearRow(5);
        }
        else if (this.BackColor == Color.Black)
        {
            moveLocation();
        }
    }
```

I realize that the 'this' keyword is referring to the whole window so it will just change the color of the entire window to red if the color is black but is there any way to change what 'this' refers to. I am trying to get it to refer to the tile that was clicked on.

Feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't want `this`, why are you using `this`? You can't modify the value of `this`, but you can use a completely different variable, and set it to whatever value you want. Your question makes very little sense; it's not clear where you got the code you're showing above, and it's not clear what code you actually need. Please improve your question, making sure to include a good [mcve]. See also [ask] for more advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: I am sorry I am very new to `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the `Windows` object here. You need to get `Panel` object to  change the `Backcolor`. You can simply cast `sender` to the `Control` object. For example:

```
private void regclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Control)sender;

    if (control.BackColor== Color.White)
    {
        control.BackColor = Color.Red;
        MessageBox.Show("Game Over");
        clearRow(5);
    }
    else if (control.BackColor == Color.Black)
    {
        moveLocation();
    }
}
```

Refer MSDN Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. It works!

Comment: Hi @ElDoubleOP can makred it as answered?

Comment: Sorry how do I do that @Ankit

Comment: You should see a right tick to the left of my answer just below the vote. You can click on that to accept this as answer.